# CoordinatorLayout and weight

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I need to create a Coordinatorlayout with a Linear Layout and a RecyclerView with the same space for both.

I've tried setting layout_weight 0.5 but the RecyclerView is taking all the space.

This is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">

     </LinearLayout>

     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/lvToDoList"            
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
     </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

     <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How can I achive that?

Regards, Diego.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

layout_weight working only in LinearLayout. So, put LinearLayout as middle layer:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/lvToDoList"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            >
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Just tried this and know nothing is shown. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Why do I need to put them inside Linear Layouts to work this out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a LinearLayout inside the CoordinatorLayout. The inner LinearLayout provides the hook so that Android can do weighted views.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">

      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">

     </LinearLayout>

     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/lvToDoList"            
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
     </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

     <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

     </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use weight like this

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10_dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="#212121"
    android:text="Button 1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/view2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="#3cff42"
    android:text="Button 2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/view3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view1" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="#f93d3d"
    android:text="Button 3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view2" />
```

Comment: CoordinatorLayout, not ConstraintLayout.